# Dynamically set registration id from query param

Tags: spring-security

I have the following controller to get registration ClientA when the endpoint is called.

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/token")
   fun token(
      @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("clientA") authorizedClient: OAuth2AuthorizedClient
   ): ResponseEntity<String> {
         val token = tokenService.getToken()
         return ResponseEntity(token, HttpStatus.OK)
   }
```

I want to have the client as a `query param` and dynamically start the OAuth2 process. How could I achieve it? sth like the following:

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/token?client={client}")
   fun token(
      @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient(${client}) authorizedClient: OAuth2AuthorizedClient
   ): ResponseEntity<String> {
         val token = tokenService.getToken()
         return ResponseEntity(token, HttpStatus.OK)
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use the `default authorization uri` and `defaultSuccessUrl("/token")`

The goal is to scale the client easily, and this solution can achieve the same.

**Solution:**

1. Register `clientA` in `application.yml`

```
               clientA:
                  client-id: Any
                  redirect-uri: http://localhost/index
                  provider: clientA-provider
                  scope: launch
                  client-name: clientA
                  client-authentication-method: none
                  authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
```

2. Now the endpoint `/oauth2/authorization/clientA` is created automatically by spring security. For getting a token, call the above url.

After successful authorization, the endpoint goes to `/token`, due to defaultSuccessUrl("/token").

The following shows the related code snippet:

```kotlin
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
      http.csrf()
         .disable()
         .oauth2Login()
         .authorizationEndpoint()
         .and()
         .tokenEndpoint()
         .and()
         .defaultSuccessUrl("/token")
```

```kotlin
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/token")
class LaunchController(private val tokenService: TokenService) {

   @GetMapping
   fun token(): ResponseEntity<String> {
         val token = tokenService.getToken()
         return ResponseEntity.ok(token)

   }
}
```